# Login loop after disabling secure boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, virtualbox, login, secure-boot

I tried disabling the secure boot (to solve an error message from VirtualBox) with `sudo mokutil --disable-validation`(as per method 2 on the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS)). After rebooting I am stuck in a login loop. If I try the wrong password I have the expected “something went wrong, please try again” message. I wanted to turn the secure boot on again in the BIOS but there I see that secure boot is still enabled (though it’s possibly a different thing?)

I have Dell Vostro 14 5459 with Ubuntu 18.04. Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: I tried and failed to log in using the tty, neither my account name nor the name in the terminal seem to be correct...

EDIT2: I just had to enter my name in all lowercase, so I’m in tty. However, I’ve checked for what seem to be the most common causes of a login loop (.Xauthority and/or tmp permissions), and everything’s alright there.

EDIT3: `startx` shows black screen and then the shell again. `sudo apt update && apt upgrade` did not help either.

Answer (score 1):

Finally realized that I could use `sudo mokutil --enable-validation` which allowed me to log in after the reboot! Still have this pesky VirtualBox problem.